# NetLogo, weighted random draw from a list: how to use rnd-extension?

Tags: netlogo

I have a list in NetLogo with values and a list of probabilities for each value. Now I want to draw a random value based on its probability (weighted random draw). I thought of using the [Rnd extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension), but I cant quite figure out how to get the weights right, please help

```
set values [1 2 3]
set probabilities [0.2 0.3 0.5]

set state ( rnd:weighted-one-of agentset reporter-task )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want/need to use two separate lists for your values and probabilities, the way to do it is to have the extension pick an *index* and use this index to access both the probability in the reporter passed to `rnd:weighted-one-of` and, once it is chosen, the value in your list. That's `example1` in the code below.

The extension is easier to work with, however, if you can put both your values and your probabilities in the same list. This is done by building a list of "pairs" (i.e., a list of lists with two items in each sublist). When you have that, you can use the second item of the pair (`item 1`) in the reporter and set your state using the first item of the pair (`item 0`). `example2` shows how to do this.

```
extensions [ rnd ]

to example1
  let values [1 2 3]
  let probabilities [0.2 0.3 0.5]
  let indices n-values length values [ ? ]
  let index rnd:weighted-one-of indices [ item ? probabilities ]
  let state item index values
end

to example2
  let pairs [[1 0.2] [2 0.3] [3 0.5]]
  let state item 0 rnd:weighted-one-of pairs [ item 1 ? ]
end
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned by Seth in the comments, you can construct your list of pairs from the two separate lists with `(map list values probabilities)`. He also mentions that the code might be "clearer with `first` and `last` instead of `item 0` and `item 1`."

`example3` integrates both suggestions:

```
to example3
  let values [1 2 3]
  let probabilities [0.2 0.3 0.5]
  let pairs (map list values probabilities)
  let state first rnd:weighted-one-of pairs [ last ? ]
end
```

Comment: How to make `pairs`, given `values` and `probabilities`: `(map list values probabilities)`

Comment: Maybe a little clearer with `first` and `last` instead of `item 0` and `item 1`?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that is so helpful! As I use hourly time steps and my probabilities are different for each hour of the day, I am using example 3, letting the probabilities change based on the hour.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use *any* probabilities, not just those that add up to one, you can do this without the rnd extension. For instance if you wanted to pick candidate 1, 2, or 3 based on the number of votes:

```
to-report weighted-rand 
  let values [1 2 3]
  ;let probabilities [0.2 0.3 0.5]
  let votes [5 7 9]

  ; calculate the cumulative probability list
  let cum reduce [
    lput (?2 + (ifelse-value (empty? ?1) [0] [last ?1])) ?1
  ] (fput [] votes)

  ; Roll a uniform random number weighted by the cumulative probability vector
  let x random-float sum votes
  let j  -1
  let found false
  while [(not found) and (j < (length cum))]
  [
    set j (j + 1)
    if (x <= item j cum) [set found true]
  ]

  report item j values
end
```

This is a little complex (especially the tricky use of reduce) but what it basically does is create a cumulative sum of the probabilities (votes) and then find the place in that list where the uniform random value fell. Then it returns the item from the list of values corresponding to the place it found.

Comment: Hi! Could you help out with converting this to Netlogo 6.0? I have troubles with changing the ?2 to -> procedures...