# Changing filtered values in a nested list

Tags: nested-lists, netlogo

I have a nested list, in which each sublist is structured as follows: `[[xcor ycor] weight]`.
Each tick I'd like to update the weight in a sample of these sublists.

I produce the sample (e.g. of size 2) from the nested list `total` using the Rnd extension (and very [helpful answers/comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615519/netlogo-weighted-random-draw-from-a-list-how-to-use-rnd-extension)):

```
set total [ [[0 1] 1] [[2 3] 2] [[4 5] 3] [[6 7] 4] [[0 1] 1] ]
set sample rnd:weighted-n-of 2 total [ last ? ]
```

Then I update the weights in the sample (let's say multiplying them by 2) and map them to their respective [xcor ycor]-pair.

```
let newWeights (map [last ? * 2] sample)
let updatedSample (map list (map [first ?] sample) newWeights)
```

How can I then replace those entries in `total`, bearing in mind that it may hold duplicate entries?

This seems to be the perfect job for `replace-item`, but I don't know how to construct an appropriate index and then pass the respective value from `updatedSample`.

Comment: What should happen in the case of duplicate keys (keys being `[xcor ycor]` pairs)?

Comment: @BryanHead The weights of all duplicate keys should be changed in `total` if that key is contained in `updatedSample`. Sorry for not being clear on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great problem. The data structure you're using is known as an [association list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_list), or alist for short, where the keys are `[xcor ycor]` and the values are weights. Given your task, it's better to use the keys to look things up rather than indices. Thus, `replace-item` doesn't really help here. Instead, we can run `map` on `total`, using the values from `updatedSample` if they're there, and defaulting to the values in `total`. First, we need a convenience function to look things up in the alists. In lisp (a language which influenced NetLogo), this is called `assoc`. Here it is:

```
to-report assoc [ key alist ]
  foreach alist [ if key = (first ?) [ report ? ] ]
  report false
end
```

Notice that `false` is returned if `alist` doesn't contain the key. We want to use the entry returned by this function if it's not false, otherwise use something else. Thus, we need another helper function:

```
to-report value-or-else [ value default ]
  report ifelse-value (value = false) [ default ] [ value ]
end
```

Finally, we can write a function that does the mapping:

```
to-report update-alist [ alist updated-entries ]
  report map [ value-or-else (assoc first ? updated-entries) ? ] alist
end
```

Here's it in action:

```
observer> show update-alist [[[0 1] 1] [[2 3] 2] [[4 5] 3] [[6 7] 4] [[0 1] 1]] [[[0 1] 10] [[4 5] 45]]
observer: [[[0 1] 10] [[2 3] 2] [[4 5] 45] [[6 7] 4] [[0 1] 10]]
```

You would want to call it like `update-alist total updatedSample`.

Comment: That's perfect and extremely instructive. Thank you very much! I guess I didn't fully grasp what I was actually doing.