# How to hatch turtles with probability

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to find a procedure to hatch a turtle based on random probability:

- 40% for A
- 30% for B
- 30% for C

How do you hatch a turtle depending on that probability? What procedure/s should I use?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like A, B, and C are breeds?  Then

```
to weighted-hatch ;; turtle-proc
  let p random-float 100
  if (p >= 60) [hatch-As 1 [init-A]]
  if (if p >= 30 and p < 60) [hatch-Bs 1 [init-B]]
  if (p < 30) [hatch-Cs 1 [init-C]]
end
to init-A
  ;;put any desired initializations here
end
```

Etc.

You could alternatively use the `rnd` extension; see [NetLogo, weighted random draw from a list: how to use rnd-extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615519/netlogo-weighted-random-draw-from-a-list-how-to-use-rnd-extension)

Answer (score 1):

Throw a dice mate! : ) Generate a random number, since you have 3 probable options you can use something like `random-float 1` this gives a number in [0,1).

Then, `if 0>= number <=0.4 hatch A`, `else if 0.4< number <=0.7 hatch B` and so on for C.

Happy coding!