# creating turtles in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I need some help in my ABM. My model is cellular automata based. The turtles are with three breeds bike, cycle and car. When simulation starts the setup procedure should create some specific count of turtles. For example:
30% of total turtles with breed bike, 
30% of total turtles with breed cycle and 
40% of total turtles with breed car. 
and the total (30% + 30% + 40%) = total number of turtles 
My code looks like following:

```
breed[bike]
breed[cycle]
breed[car]
to setup
ask patches[
sprout 1 [
let b = count bike(round (30 / 100 * count turtles)) 
let cy = count cycle(round(30 / 100 * count turtles))
let c = count car (round(40 / 100 * count turtles))
create-bike b
 ask bike[set color gray]
create-cycle cy
ask cycle[set color blue]
create-car c
ask car[set color green]
]
]
end
```

But the error occured as creat-bike, create-cycle and create-car are observers and cannot be used here.
Please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: Please post what you have so far. You will need a `breed` statement for each, and you will need some statements like `create-cars 10`

Comment: breed [bike]
breed [car]
breed [cycle]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches[
    sprout 1[
      set breed (one-of (list bike car cycle))
      ask bike[ set color gray]
      ask car[set color blue]
      ask cycle[set color green]
    ]
  ] 
end
Within Sprout creat-car do not works as it is observer. I just want 30% of total turtles with breed bike, 30% of total turtles with breed cycle and 40% of total turtles with breed car. I need my model cellular automata based.

Comment: @Aisha welcome to Stack Overflow! it's very difficult to read your code when it's pasted into a comment like that. Please edit your original question and add the code there. Then we'll be able to help you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156262/how-to-hatch-turtles-with-probability

Comment: Ok. Within Sprout creat-car do not works as it is observer. I just want 30% of total turtles with breed bike, 30% of total turtles with breed cycle and 40% of total turtles with breed car. I need my model cellular automata based.

Comment: @SethTisue I do not want to hatch turtles. I want to start simulation with the above mentioned total counts of each breed.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing a create-turtle inside a sprout statement. Both are ways to create turtles. This is the corrected version of what you have:

```
breed[bikes bike]
breed[cycles cycle]
breed[cars car]

to setup
  set num-turtles 100     ; or use a slider to set total turtle numbers
  create-bikes round (0.3 * num-turtles)
  [ set color gray
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  create-cycles round (0.3 * num-turtles)
  [ set color blue
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  create-cars round (0.4 * num-turtles)
  [ set color green
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end
```

However, it is possible that you want each patch to have one turtle (if I have interpreted your request for cellular automata correctly). In that case, you need something like:

```
breed[bikes bike]
breed[cycles cycle]
breed[cars car]

to setup
  ask patches
  [ let xx random-float 1
    ifelse xx < 0.3 [ sprout-bikes 1 [ set color gray ] ] [
    ifelse xx < 0.6 [ sprout-cycles 1 [ set color blue ] ] [
                    [ sprout-cars 1 [ set color green ] ] ] ]
  ]
end
```

I strongly suggest you do the tutorials available online at the NetLogo site before trying to code the next bit as you are missing some fundamentals. For example, `count turtles` is an instruction to report the number of turtles that already exist. You need to understand the connection between the interface and the code. You should probably also look at some of the sample models.

Comment: You used random-float here. Is this possible if I count total number of turtles and then random 0.3% turtles should have bikes, 0.2% cycles and 0.5% cars.? And each patch have 1 turtle on it.

Comment: `random-float 1` returns a number from 0 to 1 (and puts it in the variable xx in my code). You can then break up the range however you like. So if you want 30% bikes, 20% cycles and 50% cars, then the ranges are 0 to 0.2, 0.2 to 0.5 and 0.5 to 1. So simply change the 0.6 to 0.5 in the code.